# CSS Elements hidden on iPad

Tags: ios, css, ipad, hidden

I created two css classes (hidedesktop and hideonmobile) so that I could selectively hide elements depending on whether the user was on  a desktop or mobile device.

But I've noticed that elements with either class do not display on an iPad in portrait orientation despite working fine on desktop, mobile and landscape orientation.
Does anyone have any tips on how to overcome this?

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.hidedesktop{ display: none; }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
.hideonmobile{ display: none; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
       .hidedesktop{ display: none; }
       .hideonmobile{ display: block; }
    }

    @media screen and(max-width: 768px) {
       .hideonmobile{ display: none; }
       .hidedesktop{ display: block; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of your media queries will hide elements at 768px. The first value affected by your `min-width` media query is 768px and the last value of your `max-width` media query is 768px

Set your mobile max-width to 767px and your desktop min-width to something larger i.e. 992px so you media queries become

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
.hidedesktop{ display: none; }
}

@media screen and(max-width: 767px) {
.hideonmobile{ display: none; }
}
```